# How to use Aggregation Framework in MongoDB to find out hourly, daily, weekly, yearly temperature data?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

Example Data Packet (Storing in every 5 sec):

```json
{
  _id : "74uy4bf71880088hre",
   date : 2021-05-07T03:54:27.318+00:00,
   deviceId : "12345t6",
   temperature:21,
}
```

I have the last few month's data in this Data Packet formate in MongoDB, I want to Create an Aggregation Pipeline in order to retrieve Data Hourly, Daily(3 Nov-3 October), Weekly (Last 7 weeks), Monthly.

Please, anyone, have any idea how to write it. Thanks in Advance.

Extra information can ask.

Except Aggregation Framework having any other suggestions.

Expected Output for Hourly :

```
[
  {
        "dataType": "Temperature",
        "deviceID": "12345t6",
        "timing": "Hourly",
        "temperature": 0,
        "date": "2021-11-02T23:30:00.000Z",
        "hours": 1,
        
    },
    {
        "dataType": "Temperature",
        "deviceID": "12345t6",
        "timing": "Hourly",
        "temperature": 0,
        "date": "2021-11-03T00:00:00.000Z",
        "hours": 2,
    },
 .......hours:24
]
```

Here "hours": 1  means 0-1pm, & "hours": 2 means 1-2pm and so on.

Comment: can you share your expected output? usually your test case would be a count grouped by different intervals, is that for your case?

Comment: Temperatures should be stored as number, rather than strings.

Answer (score 1):

data

```
[
  {
    date: "2021-05-07T03:54:27.318+00:00",
    deviceId: "12345t6",
    temperature: "21"
  },
  {
    date: "2021-05-07T05:54:27.318+00:00",
    deviceId: "12345t6",
    temperature: "23"
  },
  {
    date: "2021-05-08T05:54:27.318+00:00",
    deviceId: "12345t6",
    temperature: "25"
  }
]
```

aggregate

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$facet": {
      "hourly": [
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": {
              $dateTrunc: {
                date: {
                  "$toDate": "$date"
                },
                unit: "hour"
              }
            },
            "avg": {
              "$avg": {
                "$toInt": "$temperature"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "daily": [
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": {
              $dateTrunc: {
                date: {
                  "$toDate": "$date"
                },
                unit: "day"
              }
            },
            "avg": {
              "$avg": {
                "$toInt": "$temperature"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "weekly": [
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": {
              $dateTrunc: {
                date: {
                  "$toDate": "$date"
                },
                unit: "week"
              }
            },
            "avg": {
              "$avg": {
                "$toInt": "$temperature"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "monthly": [
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": {
              $dateTrunc: {
                date: {
                  "$toDate": "$date"
                },
                unit: "month"
              }
            },
            "avg": {
              "$avg": {
                "$toInt": "$temperature"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/y2zlO3nzSBm)

Comment: For weekly average you should specify `startOfWeek: <Expression>`, it defaults to Sunday which could be wrong for your application.